# Mapbox - zoomWithLatitudeLongitudeBoundsSouthWest not zooming to correct location

Tags: ios, mapping, google-maps-api-2, mapbox

I am trying to use the following function `zoomWithLatitudeLongitudeBoundsSouthWest` to zoom to the extent of the uk. I have the following latlongs:

```
SouthWest = (latitude = 49.724355000000003, longitude = -8.7919210000000003)
NorthEast =  (latitude = 59.556961999999999, longitude = 2.102922)
```

So use the following:

```
[rmMapView zoomWithLatitudeLongitudeBoundsSouthWest:self.southWest northEast:self.northEast animated:YES];
```

When this is passed in to the function it returns the following projected bounds:

```
origin: (185130.482481, 6398696.510918) size: (48919.698096, 66653.088655)
```

However, this is not the extent of the UK as expected, it actually zooms in to France. During the process I also set the constraints of the map using the following:

```
[rmMapView setConstraintsSouthWest:self.southWest northEast:self.northEast];
```

When I pan around the map and zoom out, the constraints of the map are correct i.e. I can't move outside of the UK. This means that the southWest and northEast are set correctly, however, the zoomWithLatitudeLongitude function is not moving to the correct area. I use this function on smaller areas (subsections of the uk) and it seems to work correctly. Can anyone tell me if they have had similar issues or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you set center for map?

Comment: agreed.  try setting the center point and zoom level.

Comment: Compare the aspect ratio of the bounds you are requesting with the aspect ratio of your map view. If they are not the same, then there is no way that the map could zoom to those bounds exactly. It's going to make an educated guess. What is the size of your map view in pixels?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is little late, but this issue lost me a whole day of work. You are probably testing on 64 bit devices. Try your code on 32 bit devices and it should probably be working fine.

Mapbox had a problem of centering the zoom on 64 bit devices (the zoom level is ok, but the map offset is not).

I worked around this solution by setting the new center of the map after setting the zoom.
Try adding this line:

```
[rmMapView setCenterCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,lng)];
just after zoomWithLatitudeLongitudeBoundsSouthWest
where lat = (latMin + latMax)/2 and lng = (lngMin + lngMax)/2)
```

NOTE: I was passing animated:NO so this worked in my case. Try somehow animating seCenterCoordinate in your case.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason there is a problem with the MapView frame during initialisation. Updating the frame based on another view in the ViewDidLoad seemed to fix the problem.

```
[self.mapView setFrame:self.view.frame];
```

Not investigated this fully but seemed to be a good workaround.